# JVM whats running on the background

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

I have some code I made.
It's **not multithreaded**, but when I run it 
I can see that all 4 of my processors are running at 80% instead of 15%.

Can someone explain how can a non multithreaded program run on all processors.
I found some answers that say that it's a garbage collector.

Is there something more that running on the back ground ?

You can try this code (I know its not the best way to write this):

```
String ans = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    String s = "aba";
    ans += s;
    if(i % 1000 == 0)
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: For one, It may be some other process. Oracle JVM has several background threads, among them GC and HotSpot threads. You can see these utility threads in regular thread dump. On Linux you can make JVM print out thread dump by `kill -3 <java_pid>`.

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: A standard JVM will use background threads for garbage collection and cleaning up weak references.

Comment: It doesn't meter lunch any code that run for couple of seconds and doing some job. (I'm using windows 8.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if the GC and other housekeeping is really causing this behavior (you instantiate lots of string objects by concatenation). To be absolutely sure what's going on, i would recommend you to check out the VisualVM Tool.

https://visualvm.java.net/

It will display a list of all running threads and also inform you of GC activity.

Answer (score 0):

`ans += s;` create a new string and assigns it back to `ans` so it could be the garbage collector.